# Generate and fetch table statistics

Tags: oracle, statistics

I am trying to generate statistics for my tables. I am doing it with the following command:

`exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(USER, 'tab_name', cascade => TRUE);`

Then I am trying to fetch these statistics by running the following command:

> `select column_name, num_distinct, num_nulls 
>   from USER_TAB_COLUMNS 
>   where table_name = 'tab_name';`

Unfortunately, the result of this select is empty. I am lost. Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Post the **exact** table name and `SELECT` statement. `DBMS_STATS` can handle the difference between lowercase and uppercase letters in the name of the table, but  a string comparison (`= 'tab_name'`) by default performs an exact match because of binary comparison. If you did not specifically create a table with lowercase name, you should use `= 'TAB_NAME'`.

Comment: As a side note, you could have merely removed your where condition, taken a look at how the data is stored, and the resolution with why your query returns 0 results should have been obvious...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Balazs Papp was right. I needed to specify table name in upper case although create command contained only lower case.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#i78562